# Filtering Quotes by InventTable

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009

I'm trying to build a report in AX 2009 (SP1, currently rollup 6) with a primary data source of the SalesQuotationLine table. Due to how our inventory is structured, I need to apply a filter that shows only certain categories of items (in this case, non-service items as defined in the InventTable). However, it seems that there is a problem in the link between the SalesQuotationLine and InventTable such that only two specific items will ever display.

We have tested this against the Sales Quotation Details screen as well, with the same results. Executing a query such as this: [image]

...will only show quotes that have one of the specific items mentioned earlier. If we change the Item Type to something else (for example to Item), the result is an empty set. We are also getting this issue on one of our secondary test servers, which for all intents is a fresh install.

There doesn't seem to be any issues with the data mapping from the one table to the other, and we are not experiencing this issue with any other table set. Is this a real issue, or am I just missing something?

Comment: How close have you looked at the join criteria between [Quotations] and [Quotation lines]?  Look at the names of the columns that are being used in that join and then inspect the data in the table.  Have you tried splitting the query into two separate queries [Quotations]-[Quotation lines] vs [Quotation lines]-[Items]?  It could help you isolate your issue.

Comment: The Quotations -> Quotation Lines relation is still the default: `SalesQuotationLine.QuotationId == SalesQuotationTable.QuotationId`. There is no direct relation between SalesQuotationLine and InventTable, but SalesQuotationLine.ItemId has an ExtendedDataType of ItemIdSmall, which extends ItemId (no changes), which has a relation of `ItemId = InventTable.ItemId`. There are no modifications to the form data source methods that would add a filter. Table -> Line filters work fine, it seems to only be the link between Line -> Item.

Comment: Is the ItemType always set to a non-blank value (for the missing rows)?

Comment: That's correct. ItemType is an Enum with 3 values: Item (0), BOM (1), Service (2). The record will always have a value in this field (the default value being 0, Item). In addition, I don't even need to have a filter on the item table - simply bringing it into the query window is enough to trigger this behavior (IE, the join seems to be the primary issue). This also happens on all forms and reports, so isn't tied to a particular data source setup, but is global. A SQL Profile doesn't seem to turn any obvious issues, but I need to dig at it a little more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After analyzing the results from a SQL Profile run during the execution of the query, it seems the issue was a system bug. When selecting a table to join to the SalesQuotationLines, you have two options: 'Items' and 'Items (Item Number)'. Regardless of which table you select the query executes with, it joins the InventTable with the relation "SalesQuotationLines.ProjTransCode = InventTable.ItemId". 
After comparing the table to other layers in the system, I found the following block of code removed from the createLine method (in the SYP layer):

```
if (this.ProjTransType == QuotationProjTransType::Item)
{
    this.ProjTransCode = this.ItemId;
}
```

Since the ProjTransCode is no longer being populated, the join does not work except on certain quote lines that do have the ProjTransCode populated.

In addition, there is no directly defined relation to the InventTable - the link is only maintained via an Extended Data Type that is used on the SalesQuotationLine.ItemId field. Adding this relation in manually solved the problem.

Comment: My guess is that it was to be moved into one of the initBy... methods, so it would only be assigned in Project billings (implied by the name of the field) instead of every quote. It's more odd that the relation wasn't defined, even though it is stated as a relation on the MSDN documentation. It's also possible this has been fixed in subsequent rollups.